# How to make a working executable Jar file? (BlueJ)

Tags: java, executable-jar, bluej

I use the program BlueJ to code java and have recently finished a project and wish to make it into an Executable Jar file. I create one but I does Not work when I double click it. Do I have to do something specific in the program before creating the jar file? Do I have to download software for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

If properly configured the double click should execute the jar.

Check the following:

1. If the jar [manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html) contains the [Main-Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) attribute.
2. If the main class attribute is correct (points to the correct class)
3. If your jar contains all the dependencies that your program needs to run.

BTW, testing with `java -jar your_jar_name.jar` is a good option to see if your jar is really executable.